# how to overwrite the properties of an library? (colResizable.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using colResizable library for resizing. I have a div and inside the div, i have a table with colResizable and everything is working fine. But, if the width of the table is greater than the div, then the resizing function is not working.

[image]

I figured it out. Its because of the width property in the colResizable. If i disable it in console.log, its working fine.

[image]

So, how to overwrite the width property of colResizable?

this is the `plnkr.co/edit/IfwsUxGHuGVwwupHamkB?p=preview` link. Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to find the CSS file with the rule for `.JCLRFlex` and delete this rule. Be careful though, this way you might broke other styling.

Comment: yes. i did and the function of resizing was not working